# Z-index в опере для iframe

Tags: opera, css

Онлайн консультант который вылазит сам справа если прождать более минуты на странице, перекравывается видео. И этот баг остался только в опере, в других браузерах хватило z-index:10000; на iframe видео.

Как исправить это в опере?

Вот скрин и ссылка как это выглядит.
http://goo.gl/zb1Vbl
[image]

Comment: проблема тут z-index'ом не решится. Посмотрите по этой [ссылке][1] возможный вариант решения, но есть и готовые решения, можно поискать в инете.

[1]: http://rijamedia.com/blog/2011/02/simple-fix-html-content-over-flash-content-in-all-browsers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

&wmode=opaque - это нужно добавить к урлу ютубовского видео, то есть будет выглядеть так:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ugv8oJuIQjI&wmode=opaque